# Using AWK for an array

Tags: awk

I have a data file that contains a single region and then a varying number of cities/towns as follows;-

```
South,London,Guildford,Winchester
North,Manchester,Leeds
East,Norwich
```

I need to produce an output like this using AWK

```
South,London
South,Guildford,
South,Winchester
North,Manchester etc
```

It must loop through only when there is a city/town present.

Comment: What is the relevance of the condition given on the last line of the question ("It must loop through only when there is a city/town present")?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F ',' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) print $1, $i }' file
South,London
South,Guildford
South,Winchester
North,Manchester
North,Leeds
East,Norwich
```

The `awk` programs simply loops over the comma-delimited fields of each line, from field two onwards, and outputs each field together with the first field on the same line.

The `BEGIN` block just sets the output field delimiter to the same as the input field delimiter.

This would work if your input data is in a "simple CSV" format, i.e. if it is comma-delimited and if none of the fields have embedded commas or newlines.

Comment: That's great - and if I wanted to have totals by region too such as...South,London,3,South,Guildford,3,South,Winchester,3,North,Manchester,2, etc?

Comment: @Jon I don't really do follow-up questions in comments. If you have additional issues, you should ask a new question. Make sure that question is complete from the start.

Comment: I understand, no problem - thanks for the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have done in below method  and it worked fine

```
line_count=`awk '{print NR}' p.txt | sort -rn| sed -n '1p'`

for ((i=1;i<=$line_count;i++)); do No_of_columns=`awk -v i="$i" -F "," 'NR==i{print NF}' p.txt`; value=`awk -v i="$i" -F "," 'NR==i{print $1}' p.txt`;  colum_count=`awk -v i="$i" -F "," 'NR==i {print NF}' p.txt`; for ((d=2;d<=$colum_count;d++)); do awk -v i="$i" -v value="$value" -v d="$d" -F ","  'NR==i{print value","$d}' p.txt; done; done
```

output

```
South,London
South,Guildford
South,Winchester
North,Manchester
North,Leeds
East,Norwich
```