# Generating a new list from existing one based on first column

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a list in the following format:

```
group1;visitor1,visitor2,visitor3,
group2;visitor4,visitor5
```

From the list above, I need to generate a list in the following way:

```
group1,visitor1
group1,visitor2
group1,visitor3
group2,visitor4
group2,visitor5
```

Comment: Did you make some efforts towards solving this problem?

Comment: Is trailing comma in first line intended?

Answer (score 0):

This is *very* similar to [Using AWK for an array](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523484/using-awk-for-an-array) and a few other questions.  The main idea is to print each field from field two onwards on a separate line prepended by the first field.

In this case, we specify that the field separator is either `,` or `;`, and we also make sure not to print empty fields (there's an empty field at the end of the first line in the given data). The `OFS` variable that we set on the command line with `-v` is the output separator string that will be used to delimit the output fields, and `NF` is the number of fields on the line.

```
awk -F '[,;]' -v OFS=',' '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i != "") print $1, $i }' file
```

Given the data in the question, this generates

```
group1,visitor1
group1,visitor2
group1,visitor3
group2,visitor4
group2,visitor5
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using GNU sed like so:

```
sed -r 's:,$::;y:;,:,;:;:l;s:^(([^,]+)[^;]+);:\1\n\2,:;tl' file
```

For each input line I'm deleting the trailing comma, if any, then I'm switching commas with semicolons to help with printing. After that, I'm running a search and replace loop, between `:l` and `tl` to prepend the group name to each visitor on the current input line.

Comment: Those advanced in sed will realize that if there is only 1 visitor plus a trailing comma, two (unsuccessful) `s` iterations are done instead of one. This is because I've used another `s` command at the beginning to delete the trailing comma, so `t` will branch regardless. I could add another label and `t` at the beginning, but it works without :)